# Keeping a reference to a background thread in Grails?

Tags: java, grails, concurrency, quartz-scheduler, executorservice

My Grails 1.3.7 app needs to process big XML files, so I have a controller to which I upload the big file, and then I give the path of this file on the server to a background thread that does the processing so that I can return right away from the controller action.

For now, I am using the Grails Executor plugin and it works fine. I have an Upload domain object that is updated as the processing progresses (current status, number of processed elements, etc.). But now I have 2 more requirements:

- when the application crashes or the server is shutdown, I would like to intercept that and update my Upload domain to say that the process was interrupted
- I want the user to be able to interrupt the processing himself when clicking a link and possibly resume it from controller actions

Is there a way that I can persist a reference to my background task and intercept any interruption with java.util.concurrent framework (which is used by Executor plugin)?

And if I can't do it with util.concurrent, is it possible with other plugins/frameworks? I've had a look at Quartz for example, but I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to answer without fully testing it, but the [grails-executor plugin docs](https://github.com/basejump/grails-executor) state that the `callAsync` method returns a [`java.util.concurrent.Future` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

This object can be used to do two things:

1. Determine if a process has completed or been canceled.
2. Cancel a running process (even interrupting if necessary).

In theory, you should be able to save this Future in your user's session somewhere.  Then you could retrieve it later and use it to check the status and/or cancel the process as necessary.

Something like:

```
session.backgroundProcess = callAsync{...}

// later
def bgProc = session.backgroundProcess
if(bgProc && !(bgProc.done || bgProc.cancelled)) {
    // process is still running
}
```

That's just the idea, it's not tested.  I also don't know if there are issues with this leading to memory leaks.  You'd need to make sure you detached the `Future` once the process is completed.